# Issue Populating the details view grid with selectedindex gridview - ASP.NET , C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, detailsview

On My ASP.NET page i have a dropdown list - which contains all the table names from the DB. On selecting one table from the list, a gridview below is populated with the information found in that table.

Some of the tables have plenty of columns and making it impossible to view, So l included a details view to help me to view all the columns.

On selecting a row in the gridview, the details view is populated by the rows data. AS each table has different column names and numbers, i am facing problem that the DetailsView is not populated by anything and when l click 'Edit' or 'Delete'. It gives an error that the events were not handled.
Any pointers/help would be appreciated. As should be able ot edit the information, then update it in the gridview and in turn updating it in the table.

Here is my code for populating the DetailsView

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dtvInformation.DataSource = GridView1.SelectedRow.ToString();
        dtvInformation.DataBind();

    }
```

Below is my code for populating the Gridview

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format ("SELECT * FROM {0}", drpTable.SelectedValue), con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
da.Fill(ds);

GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: `GridView1.SelectedRow.ToString();` does not give you the data item being displayed in the row. The solution to this depends on how are you binding the gridview? Are you using data table? If yes then you need to do `DataRow dr = GridView1.SelectedRow.DataItem as DataRow`. And then try to bind dr to the details view. I am not sure if DataRow can be bound to DetailsView. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-DetailsView-Master-Detail-Example-Display-selected-GridView-Row-in-DetailsView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: you have to add *Edit* and *Delete* events property to your GridView.

Comment: I have added the code for binding the Gridview. Please help me with the code for editing and deleting because I'm really stuck and l don't know what to do. Please